# How to create Android applications for all resolutions?

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi,

I am a beginner in Android development. I want to create an Application which can be run on different screen resolutions. This App should then run on Android phones as well as Android tablets.

Is it possible? If so, how should I handle the UI design? Just set up different drawable folders?

Comment: actually you have to prepare images of different sizes.

Comment: it's one way, but increase the app size.......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please go through the Developers guide first. [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) provides a pretty good overview of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

It's a challenging task being honest. Most of the iPhone devs enjoy the fixed screen size but we Android devs have to go through this problem. I can recomend few practices that I'm following

- Try not to use Fixed height and weight as much as you can
- Stick to Linear Layout if the layout is not complex.  Go to relative layout only when its really mandatory.
- Use Wrap and fill parent than giving fixed sizes..

These are the few I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you just provide different layouts and resources for different screen densities and orientations as described in [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can suggest more, you can use NinePatch graphic for your application so that the images will keep the style when they rendered in different screen size, hope this can help you.