# How can i make the app accepted by all screen resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create Android applications for all resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894662/how-to-create-android-applications-for-all-resolutions)

Hi all iam developing an android app and running it on htc sensation xl.
But when i run it on other devices smaller or bigger i got my design on them differently.
i applied the code that support the sreen size in the menifest but still no change.
My question is that in eclipse we got three drawable folders if i made my design high and low and medium doese it make any change ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by reading [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) over at [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com).

Comment: Thnks guys i really appreciate

Comment: You should accept answers then.